# I get loged out when I go into my Files

Tags: system, files

Whenever I try to access my files my screen goes blank and I get logged out. When I log back in the only thing that loads is my wallpaper.

Comment: How about sharing crash reports or some `syslogs` Also what is the output of uname -a try running this command and copy paste the output.txt file io.elementary.pantheon-files | output.txt

Comment: Please edit the question with the output of `lsb_release -a` and please confirm the portion of your disk you are trying to access or opening as you open Files app is owned by you. To do so, please open a terminal window and try to `cd` into that directory. Let me what you find.